# (Python) Should I use parameters or make it global?

Tags: python, parameters, global-variables

I have many functions that all share the same parameter. They will be inputting and outputting this parameter many times.

For example:

```
a = foo
a = fun(a)
a = bar(a)

def fun(a):
     ...
     return a

def bar(a):
     ...
     return a
```

What is more pro-grammatically correct, passing parameters through a function, or having it be globally accessible for all the functions to work with?

```
a = foo
fun()
bar()

def fun():
    global a
    ...

def bar():
    global a
    ...
```

Comment: Using arguments makes it MUCH easier to reuse the code. If the functions are all related and work on similar data, you could also consider making a class to bundle everything together. This is also highly resuable.

Comment: You better pass an object and manipulate the fields in that case.

Comment: I strongly discourage the use of globals.  They are seldom used in practice.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself thinking "should I use a global?", default to "no".

Comment: this smells like a class to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For re-usability of method, passing parameter is better way.

Comment: Is there a point where it is unreasonable to pass many parameters?

Comment: @tisaconundrum you can always wrap your data in a container or object, and pass that, instead of multiple arguments...

Answer (score 6):

The more localised your variables, the better.

This is virtually an axiom for any programming language.

`struct`s in C (and equivalents in other languages such as FORTRAN) grew up from this realisation, and object orientated programming followed shortly after.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers but just for the sake of completion, as others have pointed out a class sounds like a good idea here. Consider the following.

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.a = foo

    def fun(self):
        # do stuff to self.a

    def bar(self):
        # do something else to self.a 

c = myClass(foo)
c.fun()
c.bar()
```